# Should I use quantity fields in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

If I have a schema like this:

```
type Cart {
    items: [CartItem!]!
}

type CartItem {
   id: ID!
}
```

Is id a bad practice to give the `Cart` type a `numberOfItems: Int!` field?

Comment: I don't think so. If your client may in need for the length of an array, it must not query all of the items. Type is an interface, so it has no cost if it isn't queried

Comment: Usually it is totally fine to provide computed fields. In fact moving business logic to the server and providing higher abstractions is one of the ideas behind using GraphQL. What will make this a bit prettier is a dedicated connection type that would hold more information about the relation between the two types. One example of that would be the [Relay Specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Connection-Types). You could add a `length` field to `CardItemConnection`.